# Why flexbox item relative offset parent is body and how to fix?

Tags: css, position

I try to set an img tag upon my inner text and make it at right-bottom. (not fixed! I don't want to stick that image)

However when I use "position: relative" to parent div(it also a flex item) and "position: absolute" to img, I found a problem.

It should position by parent section but its position is by "body".

I don't know why it happened. It still bothers me and makes me frustrated.

```css
body {
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;
}

.navbar {
background-color: #eff0f3;
width: 100%;
height: 72px;
}

.section {
width: 100%;
}

.section-hero {
height: calc(100vh - 72px);
background: #fff;
}

.section-hero .background {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.section-hero .logo {
position: absolute;
bottom: 120px;
left: calc(50% - 500px /2);
width: 500px;
filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 15px rgba(170,180,200,0.25));
z-index: 8;
}

.section-hero .logo img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.section-about {
margin-top: 72px;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.section:not(.fill) .inner {
margin: 0 120px;
padding: 24px 0;
}

.section-about .inner {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
width: 100%;
}

.section-about .pic {
position: relative;
}

.section-about .pic img {
position: absolute;
right: 12px;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header class="section fill section-hero">
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="inner"></div>
<div class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png"></div>
</header>
<nav class="navbar"></nav>
<section class="section section-about">
<a name="about"></a>
<div class="inner"></div>
<div class="pic">
    <img src="(picture.png)">
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the `absolute` to the div wrap not to `img` and set `relative` to the section

```css
body {
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;
}

.navbar {
background-color: #eff0f3;
width: 100%;
height: 72px;
}

.section {
width: 100%;
}

.section-hero {
height: calc(100vh - 72px);
background: #fff;
}

.section-hero .background {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.section-hero .logo {
position: absolute;
bottom: 120px;
left: calc(50% - 500px /2);
width: 500px;
filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 15px rgba(170,180,200,0.25));
z-index: 8;
}

.section-hero .logo img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.section-about {
margin-top: 72px;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
position:relative;
}

.section:not(.fill) .inner {
margin: 0 120px;
padding: 24px 0;
}

.section-about .inner {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
width: 100%;
}



.section-about .pic {
position: absolute;
right: 12px;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header class="section fill section-hero">
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="inner"></div>
<div class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png"></div>
</header>
<nav class="navbar"></nav>
<section class="section section-about">
<a name="about"></a>
<div class="inner"></div>
<div class="pic">
    <img src="(picture.png)">
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: I also want to make inner to horizontal center and vertical center, so how can I do?

Comment: to which element you want to achieve this style? to the img?